# ¿Comó imprimir un panel del tamaño de una etiqueta?

Tags: java, impresión

Buenas tardes tengo una aplicación en java donde mando a imprimir una etiqueta la cual se rellena con los datos de un formulario, todo este proceso lo hace bien el problema que tengo es que cuando sale la impresión no sale del tamaño de la etiqueta sale de la siguiente manera, el tamaño de la etiqueta: es de 10cm por 10 cm [image: el tamaño de la etiqueta es de 10cm * 10cm] 
El método que uso para imprimir la etiqueta es el siguiente:

```
 public int print(Graphics garf, PageFormat pagform, int index) throws PrinterException {
    if (index > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D hub = (Graphics2D) garf;
    hub.translate(pagform.getImageableX(), pagform.getImageableY());
    hub.scale(0.50, 0.50);
    Etiqueta.printAll(garf);
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

y con un botón lo mando a imprimir de la siguiente forma:

```
 private void ImprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        PrinterJob gg = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        gg.setPrintable((Printable) this);
        boolean top = gg.printDialog();
        if (top) {
            gg.print();
        }
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de programa", "Error\n" + e, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

¿como puedo hacerle para que la impresión salga del tamaño correcto?